# partial order, sets

Tags: order-theory

Please help to solve the following:

The set is partially ordered with respect to the “less than or equal to” relation, ≤, for real numbers.
 In following case, determine whether the set has a greatest or least element.

{x ∈ R| 0 < x < 1}

Since R is rational I assume the least element is 0+R and the greatest is  1-R. For better visibility I change the form a bit:

0+R <= x <= 1-R

Comment: What is “$0 + R$”? Can you give a definition?

Comment: There are two flaws I can see in your understanding.  First, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is translated as $x$ is a real number.  The set of rational numbers is denoted by $\mathbb{Q}$, not R.  Second, "determine whether the set has a greatest or least element".  What happens if it actually has a least element, $\epsilon>0$?  Is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$, is it in the set?  Is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>\epsilon$?

Comment: 0+R=a. Therefore 0+R Is the element "a" in a set, where for all "x" a <= x

Comment: Your element $a$ does not exist is the point of the exercise.  It is what is known as an infinitesimal and is either not a real number or is zero (and is therefore not in the set).  Try to read through my earlier comment again.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for the reply, I totally confused R-real numbers with Q-rational numbers. Since real numbers are all numbers including Q-rational I would say that e/2 >0 is in the set and also 0 < e < 1. e/2 < e. But the least element could  also be e/3 > 0. I think I understand intuitively that the element has to be a bit higher than 0 to be the least element. However I am not sure how to express that. Therefore thought of 0+ the smallest R-real number.

Comment: The argument would be the same even if the set were $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}~:~0<x<1\}$ since both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are "dense".  That is to say, for *any* two numbers $a,c\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $a\lneq c$ there is a number $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a\lneq b\lneq c$ (for explicit example, $\frac{a+c}{2}$ satisfies the expression).  In particular, with $a=0$ and $\epsilon$ your candidate for "smallest positive real number", there is a number $b$ such that $0\lneq b\lneq \epsilon$.

Comment: thank you for the comment @JMoravitz! How about following set {x ∈ Z| 0 < x < 10}. Since the set consists of integers than the least element is 1 and the greatest is 9, isn't it?

Comment: Correct.  Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense and even more specifically since $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}~:~0<x<10\}$ is finite (there are only 9 elements in it).

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, I understand better now!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case we have $X = \{x \in R \mid 0 < x < 1 \}$. No there is no greatest or least element in $ X$ since the given set is an open set. Consider the least element, this should be the smallest element in the set. For each element $ y \in X $ there exist an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $y- \epsilon \in X$. The same reasoning holds for the greatest element.

Note that the standard ordering $\leq$ is not a well-ordering for the positive real numbers since the above example does not contain a least element.

Note if we have $X = \{x \in R \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$ then there is a least and a greatest element. The least element is $x=0$ and the greatest element is $x=1$. This holds true since each value smaller than 0 is outside the set and each value larger than 1 is outside the set.